# Command for paragraph indentation after equations

Tags: equations, indentation, paragraphs

I want to write two new commands `\eqend` and `\eqcntd` so that when I put the command at the end of an equations,

1. The `\eqend` command puts a "." after the equation and forces the next paragraph to indent, regardless of the number of blank lines after the equation.
2. The `\eqcntd` command puts a "," after the equation and forces the next paragraph not to indent, regardless of the number of blank lines after the equation.

This is a sample usage,

```
\begin{equation}
f(x) = x^2 + 1 \eqend
\end{equation}
Some text here, but it's gonna get indented.
```

and another one,

```
\begin{equation}
f(x) = x^2 + 1 \eqcntd
\end{equation}


Some text here, but it's not gonna get indented.
```

Here is my NOT-WORKING solution,

```
\newcommand{\eqend}{\,. \mbox{\par}}
\newcommand{\eqcntd}{, \mbox{\noindent}}
```

Comment: You should be controlling this with the blank lines; a blank line means a new paragraph.

Comment: Thanks "You". I know the meaning of a blank line but I want to overwrite the default meaning in this case.

Comment: whatever goes in a `\mbox` never gets out of the box, so `\par` certainly won't indent the next text line.  perhaps something with `\aftergroup` would have a better chance, but i'm not in a position to experiment now.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to your question, but perhaps it might help.

I would redefine the equation environment itself. For example, with plain TeX
you could define something like (didn't test though)

```
\def\eqindent#1{$$#1\,.$$\indent\ignorespaces}
```

and use it like this:

```
\eqindent{f(x) = x^2 + 1}
Some text here, but it's gonna get indented.
```

And similarly for the `\noindent` case.
And there ought to be a similar way to do that with LaTeX.

Comment: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they are [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 1):

As Barbara Beeton has commented, forcing the first paragraph after an `equation` environment to indent can be achieved with `\aftergroup` -- use this command to add a `\par` *after* the group established by the environment.

Forcing the first paragraph after an environment *not* to indent isn't that straightforward. I came up with the following:

- I defined a new macro `\@doendeq` that will redefine `\everypar` so that it a) removes the indentation from the first paragraph following it b) reverts to its original (empty) definition. (`\@doendeq` is an abridged version of LaTeX's `\@doendpe` which is used after paragraph-making environments.)
- To change every instance of the `equation` environment to remove indents after it, one could simply add `\aftergroup\@doendeq` to the definition of `\endequation`. As you are looking for a command to modify only some instances of `equation`, I used `\csappto` from the [etoolbox](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package to *locally* add`\aftergroup\@doendeq` to `\end<\@currenvir>` (`\@currenvir` being the name of the current environment).

I suspect that there are more elegant ways to do this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\@doendeq}{%
  \everypar{{\setbox\z@\lastbox}\everypar{}}%
}
\newcommand*{\eqend}{\,.\aftergroup\par}
\newcommand*{\eqcntd}{%
  \,,%
  \csappto{end\@currenvir}{%
    \aftergroup\@doendeq
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
f(x) = x^2 + 1 \eqend
\end{equation}
Some text here, but it's gonna get indented.

\begin{equation}
f(x) = x^2 + 1 \eqcntd
\end{equation}

Some text here, but it's not gonna get indented.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks lockstep. It's great. The only problem with it is that I can't get it working in environments like eqnarray!