# Automatic noindent after quote environment

Tags: indentation, paragraphs, quoting

I need to include block quotes in my thesis, and the line following should not be indented. I am using the memoir class with XeLaTeX.

For example the following code:

```
\begin{quote}
Lorem Ipsum Dolor
\end{quote}

The quote above \\ means...
```

Tyepsets like this:

```
  Lorem Ipsum Dolor

  The quote above 
means
```

And I want it to typeset like this:

```
  Lorem Ipsum Dolor

The quote above
means
```

I realize that I could start every paragraph after `\end{quote}` with `\noindent`, but there must be an easier, automatic way.

Comment: Don't leave a blank line after `\end{quote}` (or comment out the blank line).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As Gonzalo said, *"[d]on't leave a blank line after `\end{quote}` (or comment out the blank line)"*. However, by removing the indentation from the following "paragraph", you are in fact denoting that the paragraph which includes the `quote` environment is *continued* -- which may or may not be the case. Text quotes may constitute a paragraph of their own, they may close a more substantial paragraph, and they may even be positioned in the midst of such a paragraph. Only in the last case is it appropriate to remove the indentation after the `quote` environment.

Shameless plug: My [`quoting`](http://ctan.org/pkg/quoting) package provides the `quoting` environment which also allows to control *first-line* indentation by adding/removing a blank line *before* the environment.

Comment: The paragraph following the block quote is by no means the continuation of the quote. It is similar to the first paragraph after a heading: it is a *new* paragraph but does not need to be indented.

By removing the blank line, I get many orphan and widow issues (which is logical as Tex does not see that it is a new paragraph).

Comment: Well, I disagree. :-) Text after headings always starts a new paragraph; text after quotes (like text after dispayed equations) may yor may not start a new paragraph. As for orphans, my `quoting` package includes a mechanism to avoid them.

Comment: I meant in my specific case. In general both cases are possible, but most of my blockquotes are to be construed as a separate paragraph.

Answer (score 9):

The correct way it as mentioned by others is to not leave a blank line. However, if you want to enforce this as a style for your entire document, then you could use something as below which forces the line following to not be indented (independent of if you leave a blank line or not).

This use the `\@doendeq` from [Command for paragraph indentation after equations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23677/command-for-paragraph-indentation-after-equations)

```
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\documentclass{memoir}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\@doendeq}{%
  \everypar{{\setbox\z@\lastbox}\everypar{}}%
}

\newenvironment{MyQuote}{%
    \begin{quote}%
}{%
    \end{quote}\ignorespacesafterend\par\noindent\aftergroup\@doendeq%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{MyQuote}
Lorem Ipsum Dolor (with blank lines following)
\end{MyQuote}

The quote above \\ means...

\begin{MyQuote}
Lorem Ipsum Dolor (without blank lines following)
\end{MyQuote}
%
The quote above \\ means...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this one! :-) Been looking for this for a while. This is my preferred style for environments that are *never* in the middle of a paragraph. I'm patching them with `\AfterEndEnvironment` from the `etoolbox` package.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was just having this problem in a `memoir` document, with `\chapterprecis` forcing an indent of the chapter's first paragraph.